# How I can submit two forms with one button?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have 2 forms that I wanna to submit them with one button in spring mvc

jsp page:

```
        <form:form id="form1"   method="POST"  modelAttribute="employee" >

        <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Employee </th></tr>

        <tr>

       <td>Employee ID</td>
       <td><form:input type="number" path="emp_id"/></td>

       <td>Employee Name</td>
       <td><form:input type="text"   path="name"/></td>

       <td>Designation</td>
       <td><form:label type="text"  path="designation"> </form:label></td>
       <td>
       <form:select type="text" path="designation">
       <form:option value="select" label="Select"/>
       <form:option value="Developer" label="Developer"/>
       <form:option value="Tester" label="Tester"/>
       </form:select></td>

       <td>Location</td>
      <td><form:label   path="location"/></td>
      <td>
      <form:select type="text"  path="location">
      <form:option value="select" label="select"/>
      <form:option value="Bangalore" label="Bangalore"/>
      <form:option value="Mysore" label="Mysore"/>
      </form:select></td>

      <td>Employee Type</td>
      <td><form:label type="text"  path="employee_type"> </form:label></td>
      <td>
      <form:select type="text"  path="employee_type">
      <form:option value="select" label="select"/>
      <form:option value="Permanent" label="Permanent"/>
      <form:option value="Contract" label="Contract"/>
      </form:select></td>

      <td><form:hidden  path="${id}"/></tr>
      </table>

      <br>
      </form:form>
      <form:form id="form2"   method="POST"  modelAttribute="dailyreportAttribute" >

       <table>
       <tr>
       <th>Daily Report</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

       <td>Date</td>
       <td><form:input name="date"   path="date"  /></td>

       <td>Task Type</td>
       <td><form:label path="task_type"> </form:label></td>
       <td>
       <form:select type="text" path="task_type">
      <form:option value="select" label="select"/>
      <form:option value="Technical" label="Technical"/>
      <form:option value="Non-Technical" label="Non-Technical"/>
      </form:select></td>

      <td>Description</td>
      <td><form:input type="text"   path="description"/></td>
      <td><form:hidden path="${emp_id}"/>

     </tr>

    </table>
    </form:form>
    <button class="button button-gray" onclick="submitform()"><span class="accept"> 
    </span>Save</button>
    <script>
     submitform = function(){
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    
    setTimeOut(function() {
        document.getElementById("form2").submit();
    }, 5000);
    }
   </script>
```

I'm trying to submit 2 forms with one submit button. The first table is getting inserted correctly.. but, the second table is getting  created but giving the  null value. I tried lot. I can't identify where I have done the mistake.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You need to use JS to call [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) on the other form when the `click` event fires on the button.

Comment: any submit do a page load... (or reload)

Comment: @ Spectric but it's not working...same issue only

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply submit two forms one by one as it will reload page on submit. Submit one by ajax and in its success callback submit the second form.

In your submit function add something like this.

```
var data = { EmployeId: EmpId, EmployeName: EmpName.....all other data };

$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    url: "Your post url",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        //post second form here
    }
    error: function(err){
        //If this comes here then there is some issue in ajax request you can examine by checking data in err
    }
});
```

You can get values of input fields in jquery or javascript.

Comment: how can i do with ajax..can u give me an example?? beacause i'm a beginer

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check that and if it helps you please upvote it, Thanks

Comment: i'm confused about where i have to set the submit button also

Comment: If you can show us your code may be we can help better, what all you have done so far and how you are calling ajax and second form post. What is not working, what error it is returning etc.

Comment: i think the problem is with submit button...I'm simply giving the submit as <input type="submit" value="Submit"> ...how exactly i have to call the submit button??

Comment: when i'm clicking on submit button nothing is coming...so,can u pls help where exactly and how to call the button...if it is a stupid question pls forgive me

Comment: Try with <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()"> and do your ajax call in myFunction method.

Comment: thank you..did i have to give myFunction=$.ajaax??